# Creating a property getter and setter with TypeScript Decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

I want to create a property getter and setter with TypeScript Decorator but I'm stuck on defining the function to run when the property is changed or requested.

If I have the following usage of my `Field.watch` decorator:

```
export class Test {
   ...
   @Field.watch({onSet: this.resetCssCache})
   public layoutId = 0;
   ...
   public resetCssCache() {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

and the decorator implementation is:

```
export class Field {

    public static watch(watchers: { onGet?: () => any, onSet?: (newValue: any, oldValue: any) => any }): Function {
        return (target: any, key: string) => {

            // property getter
            const getter = function() {
                return this['_' + key];
            };

            // property setter
            const setter = function(newVal) {
                if (watchers.onSet) {
                    this['_' + key] = watchers.onSet(newVal, this['_' + key]);
                }
                this['_' + key] = newVal;
            };

            // Delete property.
            if (delete this[key]) {

                // Create new property with getter and setter
                Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
                    get: getter,
                    set: setter,
                    enumerable: true,
                    configurable: true
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on `@Field.watch({onSet: this.resetCssCache})` telling that `this` is not defined.

I guess the decorator is interpreted on definition level and not on instance level. 
Is there a way to bind a non-static method to the onSet propery of my decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access a method through `this` inside a decorator, you can pass the method using `prototype`:

```
export class Test {

    @Field.watch({onSet: Test.prototype.resetCssCache })
    public layoutId = 0;

    public resetCssCache() {

    }

}
```

Be advised that this means when you call `watchers.onSet(newVal, this['_' + key]);`, the `this` inside `resetCssCache` will actually be `watchers` not the instance of `Test`. You should call it using `call` so you can pass `this` explicitly `watchers.onSet.call(this, newVal, this['_' + key])`

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am able to access the prototype via the target in the decorator, is this something new in typescript (v2.9)?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption of what 'this' represents is incorrect. It seems you are looking for instance level decorators, as you pointed out in the last sentence of your question.

I had a similar need in the past, this [issue](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/issues/13) provided the answer.

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397947/typescript-class-decorator-that-modifies-object-instance/41403157#41403157) also provides a solution.

Good luck! ;-)